# A basic question on conditional expectation and variance

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

How calculate variance of $X$ from the following statements :

$$ E[X\mid Y=1] = 2 + E[X]$$
$$ E[X\mid Y=2] = 3 + E[X]$$
$$ E[X\mid Y=3] =0$$
$$ P(Y=1)=0.5, P(Y=2)=0.3 ~~\text{and}~~ P(Y=3) =0.2 $$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Law of Total Probability for Expectations? From that we have $E[E(X|Y)] = E(X)$. If that statement is confusing to you (it certainly is for me!), just think about using Law of the Unconscious Statistician for $E(X|y)$ as a function of $y$. From all this we can calculate $E(X)$. Not sure if there's enough information to get the variance, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give more information. You can easily find
$$
  \mathbb{E}[X]
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]]
= 0.5(2 + \mathbb{E}[X]) + 0.3(3 + \mathbb{E}[X])
= \frac{19}{10} + \frac{4}{5}\mathbb{E}[X]
$$
so that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{19}{2}$, but to find the variance you will need to know
$\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ or at least $\mathbb{E}[X^2\mid Y]$. Otherwise, there may be two different random variables with the properties you list yet having different variances. For example, the condition you gave is the same as 
$$
  \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y ]
= -2Y^2 + 7Y - 3 + \frac{19}{2} \chi\{ Y \neq 3 \},
$$
so let 
$$
  X_1 
= -2Y^2 + 7Y - 3 + \frac{19}{2} \chi\{ Y \neq 3\}
$$
and let 
$$
  X_2
= -2 N(Y^2,10) + 7U(0,2Y) - 3 + \frac{19}{2}\chi\{ Y \neq 3\},
$$
where $N(Y^2,10)$ is a normal random variable with mean $Y^2$ and variance $10$, and $U(0,2Y)$ is a uniform random variable on the interval $(0,2Y)$.
Both satisfy the given conditions, yet obviously have different variances.

Comment: The identity supposedly defining $X_1$ merely stipulates that $X_1=0$ on $[Y=3]$, hence $X_1$ is undefined on $[Y\ne3]$. A typo?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it was a typo, although what I had planned to write would have been confusing without explaining what $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y ]$ must be. It is better that I was alerted that an edit needed to be made. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice solution. +1.